# Check if a type is an interface

Tags: java, class, validation, if-statement, interface

I want to validate a parameter sent to a method, it must be an interface type.
What to ask?

```
void (Class<I> interfaceType){
  if (thisisnotaninterface){
    throw...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use [`Class#isInterface()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29) to check that

And seriously, you should be reading the Javadocs before asking here.

Comment: sorry, basic stuff are hard to find everyone search for the how to check if instance implements interface.

Comment: Well if you got a Class object the logical thing to do is check the Javadoc for Class. Regardless, glad you got your answer :)

Answer (score 16):

You have got a [`Class#isInterface()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29) method that does exactly what you want: -

```
if (!interfaceType.isInterface()) {
    throw...
}
```